# Nested For-Loop never ends when assigning random number to 2D Array.

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a program using C that generates the amount of people in each household on a given street, using a random number generator inside a nested for loop.

This should be really simple, but the For-loop does not stop when I try to assign the data to the position in the array. If I take this part out, the for-loop finishes as per normal.

This one works but does not assign any data (I am using pointers testing and testing 2 to check if the loop has stopped.):

```
// populating the streets with kids
// Streets then houses, we are assuming that each street is uniform in   number of houses
int KidsInStreet[9][24];
for(int o = 0; o <10; o++){
    printf("Testing %d\n", o);
    for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
        // assign randnumber between 0 and 5 for no of kids
        int r = rand() % 5;
        // KidsInStreet[o][j] = r;
        printf("Testing2 %d\n", j);
    }
}
```

and when I try to assign the data, the loop does not stop:

```
// populating the streets with kids
// Streets then houses, we are assuming that each street is uniform in number of houses
int KidsInStreet[9][24];
for(int o = 0; o <10; o++){
    printf("Testing %d\n", o);
    for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
        // assign randnumber between 0 and 5 for no of kids
        int r = rand() % 5;
        KidsInStreet[o][j] = r;
        printf("Testing2 %d\n", j);
    }
}
```

I have 0 idea why this is happening, as it really shouldn't be an issue. 
Thank you very much for any feedback :)

Comment: Your loop limits are off-by-one, so you are indexing arrays out of range. The limit of indexing `int KidsInStreet[9][24];` is `KidsInStreet[8][23] = r;`. As this is *undefined behaviour* the actual behaviour is irrelevant.

Comment: What is the range of array indexes? For an array of nine elements the valid index range is from zero to eight (inclusive). Your outer loop goes up to *nine* which will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Array should be declared as 'int KidsInStreet[10][25]' or for loops must be changed as accordingly

Comment: Aside: `// assign randnumber between 0 and 5 for no of kids \ int r = rand() % 5;` assigns a random number in the range `0..4`. Please be careful with your upper limits!

Comment: Thank you very much, I assumed that the array went from 0-9 so 10 elements, not from 0-8. @WeatherVane

Comment: Thank you :) @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) @GAURANGVYAS

Comment: In `int KidsInStreet[9][24]` the `9` and `24` are the *number of elements*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @WeatherVane in the comments, in this line `int KidsInStreet[9][24]` the `9` and `24` are the number of elements.

Changing that line to `int KidsInStreet[10][25];` fixes the problem:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {
    // Disable stdout buffering
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    printf("Hello World\n");
    int KidsInStreet[10][25];
    for(int o = 0; o <10; o++){
        printf("Testing %d\n", o);
        for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
            // assign randnumber between 0 and 5 for no of kids
            int r = rand() % 5;
            KidsInStreet[o][j] = r;
            printf("Testing2 o%d j%d\n",o, j);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can try the code here: https://repl.it/EycD/1